# C++ inheritance confusion

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base{};

class Derived : public Base{};

int main() {
    Derived d;
    try {
        throw d;
    }

    catch(Base b) {
        cout << "1";
    }
    catch(Derived d) {
        cout << "2";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why is this program displaying output 1 and not 2? If I have thrown the `Base` class object and the output was 2, there won't be any problem as derived class is base class along with extra features. But is it the other way around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try .. Catch block always prefers the base class as priority.

if an early catch block handles a base class which has derived classes handled in catch blocks appeared below, then those derived class catch blocks will never hit - it designed in that way.

I can give a known example of std::exception class

suppose you have extended an exception class:

```
class AlgoException : public std::exception {}

try
{
    throw AlgoException ();
}
catch (std::exception) { std::cout << 1; }
catch (AlgoException ) { std::cout << 2; }
```

In above example the throw will never caught by second catch block - just NEVER

```
try
{
    throw AlgoException ();
}
catch (AlgoException ) { std::cout << 2; }
catch (std::exception) { std::cout << 1; }
```

If we do above then it will print '2' - this should be the approach of good programming practice while handling exception in try .. catch block. We should keep base class catch block below all the derived class catch blocks.

```
class AlgoException : public std::exception {}
class NewAlgoException : public AlgoException {}
try
{
    throw NewAlgoException ();
}
catch (AlgoException ) { std::cout << 2; }
catch (NewAlgoException ) { std::cout << 3; }
catch (std::exception) { std::cout << 1; }
```

If we do above then it will NEVER print '3' but prints '2'

> the base class catch block must appear most below of it derived class
>   catch block.

Comment: Please remove the `new`s from the `throw` expressions to make things actually do what you say.